# Vertical lines on the left side of iPhone 4s after it fell down. Can it be fixed without replacing its screen?

Tags: iphone, hardware, screen

I accidentally dropped my iPhone 4s and vertical lines have appeared on the left side. Although, the screen did not break. The screen works well, but I can't see the other side of the screen.
this is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDdmS.jpg

Can it be fixed without the need to replace the screen? I tried to shut it down and open it, but it didn't work. I tried a method I saw on YouTube where I would go to Settings app → Sounds → Ringtones and would play the ringtone and close and open the screen it did not work either.
Here's the link to the video i followed its' instructions : https://youtu.be/7CfYe_yNSDY

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/360415/edit) your question and include a link to the YouTube video for the method that you tried.

Comment: I don't see how playing any or all ringtones will "repair" your screen. It sounds like the scvreen or its connections have be4en damaged or moved slightly, which means that the screen will need to be removed at a minimum or probably replaced.

Answer (score 1):

The video you're referencing appears to be a hoax of some sort. The steps shown in the video make no sense.

If your screen stopped working after your phone was dropped, the screen or some other part of the phone has probably been damaged, and will need to be replaced.

Comment: the screen works fine even on the side that has vertical lines.

Comment: If the screen has vertical lines all over it, it obviously **isn't** "working fine".

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vlQZfkS here is how it looks.

Comment: What you are describing is clearly a hardware problem. The screen and/or some of the cables connecting it to the motherboard are damaged. The display needs to be replaced.